# pagination on rest api in laravel 5.1 with in request url

Tags: json, pagination, laravel-5.1

I have my URL as api/listing/stores?category=category_name for this store list under category
my code using :

```
$store_list=DB::table('s_local_store_category')
        ->where('s_local_store_category.cat_id',$business_categories_id) 
        ->join('s_loacalstors','s_local_store_category.store_id','=','s_loacalstors.localstoreid')
        ->select('s_loacalstors.*')
        ->orderBy('name','ASC')
        ->Paginate(1);
```

my output in json :

`"store":{
            "total":2,
            "per_page":1,
            "current_page":1,
            "last_page":2,
            "next_page_url":"http:\/\/in10km:8000\/api\/listing\/stores?page=2",
            "prev_page_url":null,
            "from":1,
            "to":1,
            "data":[
                {
                    "localstoreid":3,
                    "name":"cuddalore store",
                    "slug":"cuddalore-store",
                    "shortdescription":"",
                    "description":"",
                    "addressline1":"100,police line",
                    "addressline2":"center city",
                    "city":"cuddalore",
                    "state":"tamilnadu",
                    "cuntry":"india",
                    "zipcode":"607001",
                    "url":"http:\/\/in10km.com",
                    "latitude":"11.744699",
                    "longitude":"79.76802429999998",
                    "ownername":"sathish kumar",
                    "ownercontact":"95436161262",
                    "metatitle":"cuddalore",
                    "metakey":"cuddalore",
                    "metadesc":"cuddlore",
                    "verified":0,
                    "status":1,
                    "deletestatus":0,
                    "created_at":"2016-04-19 14:29:03",
                    "updated_at":"2016-04-19 14:29:03"
                }
            ]
        }
    }`

i need output like this in my json code  next_page_url should be like api/listing/stores?category=category_name&page=2

i would get with url request also with paginate page value

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view you can do the following:

```
$store_list->appends(['category' => 'category_name']);
```

Hope this helps!